# Do triple or more times reflecting telescopes exist?

Tags: telescope

Refractors only use the length of the telescope once, reflectors twice, catadioptric telescopes like those of the Schmidt-Cassegrain design three times. Have telescopes been built that reflect the incoming light at least once more?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cool question!

If you allow for flat mirrors, I've seen five myself. Answer(s) to [How did I flip some mirrors around in the dark at 3 AM and change the focal length of a 24 inch Boller and Chivens?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43357/7982) show four mirrors and there was one more on the floor below to make the beam horizontal. If you count the aluminized reflective grating as a mirror it was six.

[image: title] ALL IMAGES: click for larger size

For more info, see [Nasmyth and coudé focus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflecting_telescope#Nasmyth_and_coud%C3%A9_focus)

---

For more examples of three mirrors built into the telescope itself (as opposed to an eyepiece diagonal for viewing, see answer(s) to

- [How does this telescope work, and what is it for?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27457/7982)
- [What telescope is this, and how does it work?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/21198/7982)

[image: title] [image: title]

For more little mirrors that send light to different instruments, see answers to

- [What is a pupil slicer, and how does it work with anamorphic optics in VLT's ESPRESSO Echelle spectrograph?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27758/7982)
- [Where exactly is the modification that first corrected the spherical aberration in Hubble's primary mirror?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27912/7982)

[image: title] [image: title]

#### But three or more curved mirrors is interesting

One example is the Hubble Space Telescope using the [Wide Field and Planetary Camera 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Field_and_Planetary_Camera_2) or WFPC2.

Basically it is another whole telescope inside the Hubble, re-imaging the primary focal plane with a second purely reflective optical Cassegrain system to avoid chromatic aberration. (There would be no way to correct a fused silica lens system from 115 to 1050 nm.)

From [what-when-how Hubble: The Big Telescope](http://what-when-how.com/remote-sensing-from-air-and-space/hubble-the-big-telescope-visible-imagery-remote-sensing/)

> Figure 3.36 WFPC2 optics. Light enters the optical train from the main telescope at left.

[image: what-when-how Hubble: The Big Telescope]

Comment: I suppose increasing the focal length by reflecting the image through the entire length of the telescope again isn't too sensible/too difficult to construct

Comment: @2080 that's an interesting thought! The f/24 beam (f= 57.6 m / d = 2.4 m) is already on the longish side and the primary focal plane is pretty big so that multiple instruments sample different areas of the focal plane. For some instruments perhaps f/24 is okay, for others like the original [WFPC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Field_and_Planetary_Camera_2) it needed to be lengthened. It's really surprising to find out how little of the Hubble's primary focal plane is used at any one time for astronomy. I think you can ask that as a new question and get some interesting answers!